# How do I get the bounds in this question?

Tags: calculus, integration

I don't know how to get the bounds in this question. Please if u can I understand it better if there is a formula to find it instead of using a picture. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you have it in a smaller font?

Comment: No I don't, if you click on the picture you can resize the image to however you like it